# Post Values of "textarea" using php

Tags: php, html, forms

I had some issues trying to get my textarea value to post to my target page using php.

I have already tried to look for some code but it was outdated I think as It did'nt work for me.

My actual project Script

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test Form</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" />
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Molengo' rel='stylesheet'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Style.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="Sent2.php" method="post">
        <p>Email : </p><input type="Email" name="Email">
        <p>Nom : </p><input type="text" name="Nom">
        <p>Message : </p><textarea name"TextM" rows="15" cols="50"></textarea>  
        <input type="submit" value="Envoyer votre message" title="valider pour envoyer votre Mail" />
    </form>
</body>
```

End of My actual project Script

Everything post exactly like it should but as you already know the textarea value is blank and  do no contain any information when I'm trying to

Comment: You forgot the `=` between the attribute name and value

Comment: Thank you Clive, I was stuck for an hour just looking for something that was dumb as that xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a "**=**" at  name **=** "TextM"

Try to use code validators next time: *https://validator.w3.org/*

Comment: Thank you BobLee my script is working now
next time I'll use Code Validators yes thank you for the tip
Have a good day ;)